# Indexing Zip Files with Apache Solr

Tags: solr

I am trying to index zip files via Apache Solr.
My Zip files only contain one CSV file.

My CSV-Files look like this:

```
"N_NATIONKEY","N_NAME","N_REGIONKEY","N_COMMENT"
0,"ALGERIA                  ",0,"04.07.11"
1,"ARGENTINA                ",1,"04.07.11"
2,"BRAZIL                   ",1,"04.07.11"
…
```

I was already able to index the zip-file with following result:

`post http://localhost:8983/solr/first/update/extract?literal.id=zip2&commit=true&captureAttr=true&uprefix=attr_&fmap.content=attr_content`

```
    "ignored_":["stream_size",
      "461",
      "X-Parsed-By",
      "org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
      "X-Parsed-By",
      "org.apache.tika.parser.pkg.PackageParser",
      "stream_content_type",
      "text/plain",
      "Content-Type",
      "application/zip"],
    "div":["embedded",
      "NATION.csv",
      "package-entry"],
    "id":"zip2",
    "stream_size":[461],
    "x_parsed_by":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
      "org.apache.tika.parser.pkg.PackageParser"],
    "stream_content_type":["text/plain"],
    "content_type":["application/zip"],
    "attr_content":[" \n \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n \n   \n  NATION.csv \n \"N_NATIONKEY\",\"N_NAME\",\"N_REGIONKEY\",\"N_COMMENT\"\r\n0,\"ALGERIA                  \",0,\"04.07.11\"\r\n1,\"ARGENTINA                \",1,\"04.07.11\"\r\n2,\"BRAZIL                   \",1,\"04.07.11\"\r\n3,\"CANADA                   \",1,\"04.07.11\"\r\n4,\"EGYPT                    \",4,\"04.07.11\"\r\n5,\"ETHIOPIA                 \",0,\"04.07.11\"\r\n6,\"FRANCE                   \",3,\"04.07.11\"\r\n7,\"GERMANY                  \",3,\"04.07.11\"\r\n8,\"INDIA                    \",2,\"04.07.11\"\r\n9,\"INDONESIA                \",2,\"1\"\r\n10,\"IRAN                     \",4,\"04.07.11\"\r\n11,\"IRAQ                     \",4,\"04.07.11\"\r\n12,\"JAPAN                    \",2,\"04.07.11\"\r\n13,\"JORDAN                   \",4,\"04.07.11\"\r\n14,\"KENYA                    \",0,\"04.07.11\"\r\n15,\"MOROCCO                  \",0,\"04.07.11\"\r\n16,\"MOZAMBIQUE               \",0,\"1\"\r\n17,\"PERU                     \",1,\"04.07.11\"\r\n18,\"CHINA                    \",2,\"04.07.11\"\r\n19,\"ROMANIA                  \",3,\"1\"\r\n20,\"SAUDI ARABIA             \",4,\"04.07.11\"\r\n21,\"VIETNAM                  \",2,\"1\"\r\n22,\"RUSSIA                   \",3,\"04.07.11\"\r\n23,\"UNITED KINGDOM           \",3,\"04.07.11\"\r\n24,\"UNITED STATES            \",1,\"04.07.11\"\r\n \n\n \n  "],
    "_version_":1615098997961129984}]
```

What I want is this:

```
    "N_NATIONKEY":0,
    "N_NAME":"ALGERIA                  ",
    "N_REGIONKEY":0,
    "N_COMMENT":"04.07.11",
    "id":"84f3e0f3-8b13-47d8-818f-52504f79d91a",
    "_version_":1615098850670804992
```

Here I am able to search after specific columns.

How can I index zipped files like this?
The documentation says that it should be able with Tika, but i don't realy get it.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to get your content indexed as an actual csv update if you go through the Tika handler, as Tika is usually more concerned with getting raw content (and its metadata) out of the file instead of structuring the embedded content into separate updates.

Comment: Do you think there is an other way to do it?

Comment: Unzip it in your application posting it to Solr, then post it directly to the update handler endpoint as regular CSV files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is being done with .gz files in upcoming (7.6) Solr, see [SOLR-10981](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-10981). This does not cover zip though.

In general, you probably just want to unzip file and stream it directly to Solr. bin/post command does allow to take file content from the standard input, you just need to make sure the content type is correct. Check `bin/post -h` for details.